# Value of pointer in Parse.com javascript

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have a pointer in one of my `Parse.com` datastore objects. I need to extract the `objectId` from it. This is the json Customer object in my cloud code:

```
"Customer":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"oowk8Vgcyg"},
```

I tried

```
var customer = request.object.get("Customer")
```

This prints out `[object Object]`.

Now how do I get the `objectId` from it? I tried

```
customer.objectId
```

or

```
customer[objectId]
```

or

```
customer["objectId"]
```

or the various with or without quotes

```
customer.get(objectId)
```

but none works. What's the correct syntax?

Comment: What is the result of console.log(request.object.get("Customer"))?

Comment: @howderek it's [object Object]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `customer.id`

The Parse object looks different than the JSON you send.

https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#objects-retrieving-objects

Comment: It comes as undefined.

Comment: The correct syntax is customer.id; I found it in the link you provided so if you add this to your answer I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it like this.

For example I want to get the objectId of the class User that has a pointer from another class

var userId = object.get('User').id;

hope it helps.